# Does a router handle tcp packets with unknown source ip?

Tags: router, tcp, ip

When i add a different source ip (in public range) to the header of a tcp paket will my gateway proceed that paket as i set the source ip even if it is in an unknown subnet or will the gateway add his own real ip anyway? i cant test it because i just have 1 ip. thank you

Comment: A TCP segment doesn't have any IP addresses associated with it. Assuming you are referring to an IP packet, the answer will entirely depend on the features available on your router/gateway and how it is configured.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

My previous answer (which I could not delete ,unfortunately, because it had already been accepted as a correct answer) did not not answer the question,and so here is the edit.

If NAT is in operation on the gateway router, yes the IP address you have inserted on the packet will be changed, but it  nevertheless would have been changed by NAT even if it was still the original one.If NAT is not in operation, the packet will be forwarded as is.But it all depends on the configurations you have.

Comment: Why did you accept this answer as best? It doesn't seem to address your question, since it's focused on unknown *destination* addresses, not unknown *source* addresses.

Comment: This doesn't address the question at all. Specifically, it has nothing to do with the source address. The only time the routing table may come into play with a source address is if the router supports and is configured to do some sort of reverse path forwarding lookup.

Answer (score 0):

Based on what I know it is possible to do so. This is how DoS amplification is done. Router makes decisions based on the destination IP address of a packet then the destination node would respond to the source IP address of the packet it receives.

Answer (score 0):

A tradtional router does not care about the source address, only the destination. So it would just forward the packet as-is.

However in the modern world there are a number of complications which make it impossible to give a definitive answer without knowing both what the gateway is and how it is configured.

- Firstly there may be explicit firewall rules in place to drop such traffic.
- Secondly there may be "reverse path filtering" in place to drop traffic that does not appear to have come from the right place.
- Thirdly the gateway may implement NAT. Depending on it's configuration it may apply this only to known LAN side addresses or it may apply it to anything that passes from the local side to the Internet side.